# Angular and casting

Tags: angular, typescript

I am writing a small Application in Angular4 which is using AWS nodejs sdk.
I have wrapped the aws calls with an observer

```
getVPCs(creds: AWSCredentials): Promise<Vpcs> {
      const func = (params, cbk) => this.createEC2Client(creds).describeVpcs(params, cbk);
      return this.genericDescribeOperation(func, {});
   }

genericDescribeOperation(func: (param, cbk) => void, parms: any) {
const observer = Observable.create(o => {
  func(parms, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      o.error(err);
    } else {
      o.next(data);
      o.complete();
    }
  });
});
return observer
.toPromise();
```

}

i have create a model class to work with

```
export class Vpc {
   CidrBlock: string;
   VpcId: string;
   Tags: Tag[];

   get Name() {
     console.log('naaaaaaa');
     return 'name';
   }
 }


export class Vpcs {
  Vpcs: Vpc[];
 }
```

how ever when i try to log the Name property i get undefined. Name is just a property that i want to add. what did I miss?
thanks

Comment: Where do you ever call `new Vpc()`? If you don't, how could you possibly have an instance of Vpc being created?

Comment: I thought that by casting - it will take care of it ...

Comment: There is no casting in TypeScript. And if there was, the cast would throw an exception saying that the object you cast is not an instance of Vpc. You can't take a Banana, cast it to a Car, and have the Banana magically transformed to a Car.

Comment: Typescript does not have type casting. What it has is type assertions, where you can override the types the compiler. That however is only at build time, nothing happens at runtime. You will need to call new yourself if you want to create an instance of a class.